# WinForm insert data into wrong row in access table

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I created a form that takes a users name and inserts it into an access table. Another form takes an int from users pressing certain radio buttons. Now when the user's presses save the name is put into the first row and the int is put into the second row. I want them both into the same row so the users can see their results.

How would I be able to change this

This is the code that saves the users' name

```
{
                OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();
                string myQuery = "INSERT INTO name(name)  VALUES('" + NameTextBox.Text + "')";
                OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);
                try
                {
                    label1.Text = myQuery;
                    myConnection.Open();
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error connectiing" + ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    myConnection.Close();
                }
```

This is the code that adds the int to the database and shows the users their score.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = score.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(score.ToString(), "Results");


            OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();
            string myQuery = "INSERT INTO name(score) VALUES('" +score+ "')";
            OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);
            try
            {
                {
                    label5.Text = myQuery;
                    myConnection.Open();
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Score Saved");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error connectiing" + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                myConnection.Close();
            }
```

Any help would be appreciated with my issue I'm having.

Comment: The data access library is ADO.NET, not WinForms. `INSERT` always inserts a new row, it doesn't update existing rows. That's the job of the `UPDATE` command. BTW concatenating strings like this allows SQL injection attacks and can lead to conversion errors. Imagine what would happen if someone entered `'); drop table name;--`.  Use parameterized queries instead. You need to learn how SQL and ADO.NET works before saving data to a database

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hi, the system is just a simple system that is being used for an assignment. I know about the SQL injection problems which is actually a part of my report. However, now when I change INSERT to UPDATE I'm getting a syntax error. When codes do I actually need to add.

Comment: You need to actually read how to write SQL statements, not ask people to write them for you. Otherwise you'll keep making errors and end up wasting an entire day to do what only needed 5 minutes. Try the SQL queries in Access before writing the code. `UPDATE` has a different syntax. Google `SQL UPDATE` at least

Comment: Hi, I tried googling it I can't find the code properly. Could you prove me with the code since I'm on a time crunch? I do have an understanding of SQL statements but I was stuck and this was my first time asking a question since I'm really stuck and don't have allot of time to deep dive into finding a fix.

Comment: SQL parameters are not just about security, they also prevent syntax errors. Always use parameters. You should also dispose your connection and command objects. with `using`